# Why is it making a blank then a loop

Tags: javascript, html

`ip.txt` contains an IP address and port to a web app. I want a button to be able to read the contents of `ip.txt` then set the href as that. I've been trying to do it for a while with loads of different methods but I can't get it to work.

This is the latest one I tried (just opens `about:blank`)

---

Code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Quick deploy</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    </head>
        <body>
            <style>
                .center {text-align: center; position: absolute;}
            </style>
            <script>
            function a() {
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                client.open('GET', 'ip.txt');
                client.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    window.open(client.responseText);
                }
                client.send();
            }
            </script>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger center" href="#" onclick="a();">Connect to instance</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL '%3[THE ADDRESS IM TRYING TO GET TO]'

Comment: You're looking for the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method

Comment: Can you clarify what's your problem ? Have you tried opening the developer tools in your browser ? Do you see any error in the javascript console ?

Comment: ```Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL '%3[THE ADDRESS IM TRYING TO GET TO]'.```

Comment: The file has `%3` at the beginning of it.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst thanks, I'll try and use that after I manage to get the address. For now I just want to get the actual button to send me to the page.

Comment: @Barmar I know, the file doesn't

Comment: The error message is pretty clear that there's something before the URL. There's nothing in your code that adds that to the URL.

Comment: The file only has the address in it, nothing else. Literally just checked now to make sure

Comment: Maybe a non-printing character, like BOM? Check with a hex dump.

Comment: just realized `%39` means the number `9` which is the start of my IP. I think the first character is in utf-8, but I don't know why as the text file just has it in the default format (ANSI). (thanks @Barmar). How could I resolve this? Only the first digit of the address is utf8 encoded

Comment: The argument to `window.open()` is supposed to be a URL, not an IP. You need `http://` before the IP

Comment: I'll update the script that produces ip.txt to add http:// beforehand

Comment: UTF-8 for `9` is the same as ordinary ASCII.

Comment: All 7-bit ASCII characters have the same representation in UTF-8.

Comment: It works (kind of)! It opens 1 blank tab, and 2 tabs with the correct address

Comment: thanks for the help so far

Comment: @IgorRetesz do you mean it opens 2 tabs now? [of the correct address,  when only one is expected] Can you post updated code?

Comment: same code, just changed the text file to have 'http://' prior to the rest of the address. After I did that 1 blank tab opens and 2 tabs which are correct. I'm only expecting one tab to open

Comment: Have you consider using `fetch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to implement original AJAX request, you have to check xhr status:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        window.location.href = xhr.responseText;//here is your data
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'ip.txt');
xhr.send();
```

You have JQuery enabled, why not use `$.ajax` instead, make more sense.

```
function a(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'ip.txt',
    success: function (data){
      //data is content of ip.txt
      debugger;//check what's inside.
      if(!!data){
        window.location.href = data;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

BTW, as an optimization, use `json` format as instead, it make more sense to get formatted data without decoding & encoding:

content of ip.json:

```
{
 uri:"..."
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid bringing in jQuery. If we can't find a solution in javascript then I'll have to go with this

Comment: But you already have JQuery enabled. why not remove the line from you example code. and bootstrap need the line as well.

Comment: Oh I forgot I brought that in, I had it before and got rid of it

Comment: BTW, why not json file to store your data, it makes much more sense. ip.json: {uri:"http://sss:8088/xxx/..."}

Comment: Nobody else is bringing in anything (I know it's been a short amount of time, just need to fix this quickly), so I guess I'll use jQuery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IgorRetesz answer updated. you just need to check status before process responseText.

Comment: The one you had before works fine. I just had to bring in jquery uncompressed instead of jquery slim